# Wait until multiple functions, which may or may not call ajax internally, are complete in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I am currently validating a few inputs clientside. When the user submits the form, I want to check the values for the form inputs, and then do something once all the checks are complete

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var input1 = $('form #input1');
    var input2 = $('form #input2');

    //validate both input values
    validate_input(input1);
    validate_input(input2);

    //wait until all validation complete to execute code here

    return false;
});
```

Here, the "validate_input" function will check the input value. If it passes the initial checks (such as character length), then it will make an AJAX request for further validation (ex. checking if username is taken). Something like this:

```
function validate_input(input){
    value=input.val();
    if (value.length<4){
        //code to execute if input is too short
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({             
            type: 'get',
            url: check_input_url,
            data: input.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if (data=="invalid") {
                    //code to execute if invalid
                } else {
                    //code to execute if valid
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am currently using jQuery.when() and .done() functions, but the done() function does not wait until all the validate_input functions are completely done (including AJAX callbacks called from validate_input)

```
$.when(
    validate_input(input1),
    validate_input(input2)
).done(function(){
    //code here
});
```

How would I wait until all the validate_input functions are complete (finished with any possible AJAX callbacks), before executing further code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see you `validate_input` function return anything. If you want to wait, you need to return a promise, so that you don't pass `undefined` to `$.when()`:

```
function validate_input(input){
    var value=input.val();
    if (value.length<4){
        return …; //code to execute if input is too short
    } else {
        return $.ajax({
 //     ^^^^^^
            …
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: that was it, I was not returning the ajax object!

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputsLength = 0, // or maybe set it to $('form input').length
    inputsReady = 0;
function checkInputsValidation(){
    if (++inputsReady === inputsLength) YOURSALLINPUTSAREVALIDFUNCTION();
}
function validate_input(input){
    inputsLength++; // remove it if you already set inputsLength
    // blablabla
    $.ajax({             
        type: 'get',
        url: check_input_url,
        data: input.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if (data=="invalid") {
                //code to execute if invalid
            } else {
                checkInputsValidation();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** i just updated my answer. it is more likely to fit your needs now. i've added a parameter to the callback function.

use callbacks with anonymous functions and chain them:

**1.** add a parameter for the callback function and the callback function call:

```
function validate_input(input, callback){
    value=input.val();
    if (value.length<4){
        //code to execute if input is too short
        callback(false);
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({             
            type: 'get',
            url: check_input_url,
            data: input.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if (data=="invalid") {
                    //code to execute if invalid
                    callback(false);
                } else {
                    //code to execute if valid
                    callback(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**2.** when calling your function multiple times, chain it with anonymous functions (which are executed after `success` in your `$.ajax`-request has been fired):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var input1 = $('form #input1');
    var input2 = $('form #input2');

    //validate both input values
    validate_input(input1, function(result){
        if(result == true)
        {
             validate_input(input2, function(result){
                 if(result == true)
                 {
                    //wait until all validation complete to execute code here
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    return false;
                 }
             });
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```