# JQuery: show/hide my loading-gif-div while operations are done

Tags: jquery, loading, internet-explorer-10

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I wasn't able to find a solution for my problem yet.

I would like to append/remove a div with my loading gif, while i make some other DOM-Operations(some ajax, some appends, some slideDowns).

Here is a jsfiddle sample

https://jsfiddle.net/qmzz4xt9/2/

As you can see, my text "Loading" will not be displayed during the "FillMyTable" function. You can remove "Load(false)" for testing.

In my website:
At the moment i click my button, i have to wait about 5-6 seconds, till i see the content. My loading-gif is there only for a blink of an eye, like in the fiddle ahead.

Simple call:

```
$('#btnLoad').click(function(){
  ShowWaitGif(true);
  FillMyTable(); //takes about 5secs
  ShowWaitGif(false);
});
```

I hope you understand my problem and my english (i'm from germany).

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: How many ajax calls do you have? Is it static ? You can count how many ajax `success` you have and then, when counter==n, then you remove your loader. Cannot help more than this without more code, sorry.

Comment: Thank you @EdenSource for your fast answer. The number of ajax operations is dynamic. My function does more than the simple ajax requests. I supposed that jquery always waits between its functions. I added a simple code block below Step 3 in my Question.

Comment: Added a jsfiddle to make the problem visible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait until multiple functions, which may or may not call ajax internally, are complete in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651172/wait-until-multiple-functions-which-may-or-may-not-call-ajax-internally-are-co)